# Mixed-up CSS on Production Build of vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli, quasar-framework

I have an issue in which the production build, which is created by `npm run build` differs from the development build, which is provided by `npm run serve`. The generated CSS on production differs from CSS on development.

**Background**

Due to changes in standard, some part of an existing application that was developed using Vuetify framework needs to be migrated to Quasar. Vuetify was installed first using `vue-cli`. Quasar was added later using `npm`. Application is in multi-page mode.

**Problem**

When viewing the page through `npm run serve`, pages that have been migrated to Quasar is shown correctly. However, when trying to deploy it in production through `npm run build`, the same page breaks. All spacing and margin in the page is off. After inspecting the resulting CSS, it turns out some CSS class is overriden to Vuetify's values.

I have tried to split the chunk for each page, to no avail.

The following is the snippet of my `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/static/dist/' : '/',
  outputDir: '../flask/web/static/dist',

  transpileDependencies: ['quasar', 'vuetify'],

  pages: {
    dashboard: { // vuetify page, no problem.
      entry: 'src/pages/dashboard/index.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'dashboard.html',
      title: 'Dashboard',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'chunk-dashboard-vendors', 'dashboard']
    },
    page2: { // quasar page, the one with problem
      entry: 'src/pages/page2/index.js',
      template: 'public/quasar.html',
      filename: 'page2.html',
      title: 'Page2',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'chunk-page2-vendors', 'page2']
    },
    page3: {
      entry: 'src/pages/page3/index.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'page3.html',
      title: 'Page3',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'chunk-page3-vendors', 'page3']
    },
    // other page definitions...
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    quasar: {
      importStrategy: 'kebab',
      rtlSupport: false
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const options = module.exports
    const pages = options.pages
    const pageKeys = Object.keys(pages)

    // Long-term caching

    const IS_VENDOR = /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
    config.optimization
      .splitChunks({
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            name: 'chunk-vendors',
            priority: -10,
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 2,
            test: IS_VENDOR,
            enforce: true
          },
          ...pageKeys.map(key => ({
            name: `chunk-${key}-vendors`,
            priority: -11,
            chunks: chunk => chunk.name === key,
            test: IS_VENDOR,
            enforce: true
          })),
          common: {
            name: 'chunk-common',
            priority: -20,
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 2,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      })
  }
}
```

The following are snippets from each of the page's entry file.

*src/pages/page2/index.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Page2 from './Page2.vue'
import '@/plugins/quasar'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(Page2)
}).$mount('#app')
```

*src/plugins/quasar.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import '@/styles/quasar.scss'
import iconSet from 'quasar/icon-set/mdi-v5.js'
import '@quasar/extras/mdi-v5/mdi-v5.css'
import { Quasar, Notify } from 'quasar'

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  config: {},
  components: {},
  directives: {},
  plugins: {
    Notify
  },
  iconSet: iconSet
})
```

*src/page3/index.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Page3 from './Page3.vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(Page3)
}).$mount('#app')
```

*src/plugins/vuetify.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
})
```

Any idea how to split the code properly between different pages, both in production and development build, so that the CSS does not override each other?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 12):

What solved my problem was adding:

```
css:{
  extract:false  
}
```

To the vue.config.js file in root directory

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you for saving me a lot of time and stress. This worked like a charm.

Comment: It didn't work until I changed it to `true` IDK why